# middle mode avg calculating of an float array

Tags: c++, c

I`ve wrote a code to calculate middle,mode and average of a float array but just when I input the first number I encounter with the"...has stopped working" error in dev c.in vs 2012 also it doesn t work.why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
float avg(float [],int);
void mode(float [], int);
float middle(float [], int);
int main(){
    int i,t=5;
    float a[t];
    for (i=0;i<t;++i)
        scanf("%f", a[i]);
    printf("avg= %f\n", avg(a, t));
    printf("middle= %f\n", middle(a, t));
    //printf("mode= \n", mode(a[]));
    mode(a, t);
    return 0;
}
float avg(float a[], int t){
    float s;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<t;++i)
        s+=a[i];
    return s/t;
}
 float middle(float a[], int t){
    int i,u;
    float h;
    for(i=0;i<t-1;++i)
        for(u=1;u<t;++u)
            if(a[i]>a[u]){
                h=a[i];
                a[i]=a[u];
                a[u]=h;
            }
    if(t%2==0)
        return (a[t/2]+a[t/2+1])/2;
    else
        return (a[(t+1)/2]);
}
void mode(float a[], int t){
    float b[t],h;
    int i,u;
    for(i=0;i<t;++i)
        b[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<t;++i)
        for(u=0;u<t;++u)
            if (a[i]==a[u])
                b[i]++;
    for(i=0;i<t-1;++i)
        for(u=1;u<t;++u)
            if(a[i]<a[u]){
                h=a[i];
                a[i]=a[u];
                a[u]=h;
            }
    printf("%f\n", a[0]);
    for(i=1;i<t;++i)
        if(a[0]==a[i])
            printf("%f\n", a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%f", a[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%f", &a[i]);
```

scan to the location where you want to store the value and here it is `&a[i]`

```
 float s;
```

`s` is uninitialized in the function avg() and using uninitialized variables lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @volerag Check the edits .. These are what I can figure out at first glance debug and see where it is crashing

Comment: Yes, now it doesn't. +1 :)

Comment: @volerag Good for you :) Oh BTW you are not the OP :)